# Creating Columns Based on Data

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I have a very very large dataset. What I want to do is dynamically create column names based on criteria. Example Below:

```
   Key         Type 
   cust1       Red
   cust1       Blue
   cust1       Yellow
   cust2       Red
   cust2       Blue
   cust2       Green
```

There will be much more data in Type Prob like 100 different color types. When I query structure to look like the below. Columns and Data

```
Key     Red Blue Yellow Green
cust1   Red Blue Yellow
cust2   Red Blue        Green
```

if I write the ask TOM code like the below:

```
procedure go_fishing( p_cursor in out t_cursor)
as
l_query long := 'select fish_id';
begin
    for x in (select distinct fish_type from fish order by 1 )
    loop
        l_query := l_query ||
           replace( q'|, sum(decode(fish_type,'$X$',fish_weight)) $X$|', '$X$',
                   dbms_assert.simple_sql_name(x.fish_type) );
   end loop;

   l_query := l_query || ' from fish group by fish_id order by fish_id';

   open p_cursor for l_query;

  end;



How can I execute it? exec goFishing_pkg.go_fishing(:x)
```

Comment: Here is another for oracle https://asktom.oracle.com/pls/asktom/f?p=100:11:0::::P11_QUESTION_ID:4471013000346257238

Comment: not even from stack exchange..... Its from ask tom

Comment: Sorry, I did my first search and got a Sql Server result, when realize the question require oracle did a second search and not stackoverflow on first result page.  But if you do a litle search Im sure you can find one here.  Search by `Oracle Dinamic Pivot`

Comment: But the process in Sql Server is the same, build  a string and execute it.

Comment: I was looking at the sql server one but not able to translate into PL SQL

Comment: This was the only example I got from Stack Exchange for Oracle but its the 10g way and is bad as a case statement. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14155418/oracle-how-to-pivot-my-table/14155582#14155582

Comment: whats is the problem of doing the sql version? or reading the tom article?

Comment: I have the answer very easy and clear for this question but i need to put it as an answer not comment because the code need to be clear